# Qt Creator phonon errors

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am using qt cretor 5.1 and trying to create music player. I wrote two different codes . The one is with phonon and  the other is  with mediaplayer. But when i run the phonon code,they give error like that Unknown module in QT:phonon .
When i run media player, it gives such error: Cannot open include file:'QMediaPlayer':No such file or directory.

Does any one have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the Multimedia module, you need to add `multimediawidgets` to your `QT` variable in your project file:

```
QT += multimediawidgets
```

Note that Phonon no longer exists in Qt 5. Use the Multimedia module instead.